# how this program works and why the answer- (4) C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>   


using namespace std;


int* fun() {

    return new int[2];
}

int fun(int *p){

    delete[] p;
    return 0;

}

void fun(int *p, int q){

    p[q]*= 2;

}

void fun(int *p, int q, int r){

    p[q] = r;

}


int main(){

    int *v = fun();
    fun(v,0,1); fun(v,1,2);


    fun(v,0);

    cout<< v[1]+ v[0];
    fun(v);
    //the answer gives 4.
}
```

Comment: A good time to start to learn a debugger

Comment: Please also format your code, it would make it nicer to read.

Comment: Best to get more specific. What in the program is giving you difficulty? Are you stuck on some bit of syntax? For example, if you do not understand what happened here `int* fun() {

    return new int[2];
}` the best help you can get is going to be "Go and re-read the first few chapters of your text book."

Comment: I will try , i am just new in this site, tnxs

Comment: i am just trying to figure it out how it works and how it gives this result.

Comment: Operator Overloading allows multiple functions with the same name.

Comment: Thanks   Audrey Brooke  for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Because of operator overloading, you are allowed to have as many functions as you want with the same name, in this case, fun, as long as they have different parameters.

- So the first call to fun creates an empty array with size 2 and assigns it to the variable v.
- The second call sets the value at index 0 of the v to 1. So, `v[0]`=1.
- The third call sets the value at index 1 of v to 2. So, `v[1]`=2.
- The fourth call multiplies the value at v[0] by 2. So, `v[0]`=2.
- `cout` prints the addition of `v[0]` and `v[1]` which = 4!
- The last call to fun deletes the array (which was dynamically allocated, thus preventing memory leaks).

Comment: This is just normal overloading not operator overloading, as the functions aren't member functions.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the main method,

You are setting a pointer v to the method `fun()`.

By calling `fun(v,0,1)` and `fun(v,1,2)`, you are using operator overloading to call a fun function that is taking in three parameters.

The first call will create an array with size 2 as denoted by `int[2]`, and then the second call will set the 0th index of the v array to 1, then the third call will set the array value at index 2 to 2, and then the fourth call will multiply the 0th index of the array by 2 (denoted by your fun method with two parameters).

Your print statement then adds together the values of v[0] and v[1], resulting in a sum of 4.

I believe then the last method call of `fun(v)` will then result in deleting the array and then ending the program, denoted by return 0.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
int main(){

    int *v = fun(); //call a function that creates an array of 2 items in the heap and returns a pointer to it
    fun(v,0,1); fun(v,1,2); //call functions that write values (1 and 2) to 0 and 1 element of the array by the pointer v


    fun(v,0); //call functions that multiply the value of the index 0 by 2 obtained by the pointer v array (1*2=2)

    cout<< v[1]+ v[0]; //output of sum of numbers (2+2=4)
    fun(v); //call a function that frees memory in the heap on the received pointer
    //the answer gives 4.
}
```